# Unable to convert date-time string

Tags: tcl

What could be the reason for the TCL error:

> Tcl Error: unable to convert date-time string "Wed May 14 05:20:15 RET 2014"

when executing `clock scan $Date`

```
% echo $tcl_version
8.4
% info patchlevel
8.4.19
```

Saw few suggestion to upgrade to TCL 8.5, but want to know whether the issue can be resolved in 8.4 itself.

Comment: RET is not a meridian recognised by Tcl. You might want to use the timezone difference such as `0400` for `GMT+0400` (at least, that's what appears to work for me, I'm using 8.6 though). Are you from Reunion Is? I think that's the closest member to me I've seen on here so far =P

Answer (score 1):

This is the hoop I think Tcl 8.4 makes you jump through: (tested in Tcl 8.3.3)

```
% set dt "Wed May 14 05:20:15 RET 2014"
Wed May 14 05:20:15 RET 2014
% regsub RET $dt "" dt_alt
1
% set offset +4
+4
% set epoch [clock scan "$offset hours" -base [clock scan $dt_alt -gmt 1]]
1400026815
% clock format $epoch -gmt 1
Wed May 14 00:20:15 GMT 2014
```

where

- you have to remove the "unknown" time zone from the datetime string, and
- you have to know that RET == GMT+4

---

Tcl 8.5 still cannot parse that exact string:

```
% set dt "Wed May 14 05:20:15 RET 2014"
Wed May 14 05:20:15 RET 2014
% clock scan $dt
unable to convert date-time string "Wed May 14 05:20:15 RET 2014": syntax error (characters 19-22)
```

but

```
% set epoch [clock scan [string map {RET ""} $dt] -format {%a %b %d %T %Y} -timezone :Indian/Reunion]
1400030415
% clock format $epoch
Tue May 13 21:20:15 EDT 2014
% clock format $epoch -timezone :Indian/Reunion
Wed May 14 05:20:15 RET 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax problem. Date should be "Wed May 14 05:20:15".
Example:

```
set Date "Wed May 14 05:20:15"
clock scan $Date
```

or if you have Date = "Wed May 14 05:20:15 RET 2014" then:

```
clock scan "[lindex $Date 0] [lindex $Date 1] [lindex $Date 2] [lindex $Date 3]"
```

Comment: No, the problem is that Tcl 8.4's clock command does not recognize the "RET" time zone. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations